# ios sprite kit bodyWithBodies not working

Tags: ios

```
    SKSpriteNode * test = [[SKSpriteNode alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(100, 100)];
[self addChild:test];
[test setPosition:CGPointMake(300, 300)];

//  bottom
CGSize textureSize = CGSizeMake(100, 100);
SKPhysicsBody *physicsBottom = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:textureSize];
physicsBottom.categoryBitMask = ColliderBottom;
physicsBottom.contactTestBitMask = ColliderBottom | ColliderObstacle;

//  working...
//    test.physicsBody = physicsBottom;

//  not working...  this line is problem.
test.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[physicsBottom]];
```

didEndContact not working by this code.

```
test.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[physicsBottom]];
```

what's problem????

```
typedef enum {
ColliderObstacle    = 1 << 0,
ColliderCharacter   = 1 << 2,
ColliderLeft        = 1 << 3,
ColliderRight       = 1 << 4,
ColliderBottom      = 1 << 5,}ColliderType;
```

// not wokring... this line... I don't understand.
Why didEndContact event not working???????

Comment: I cant see anywhere how you create physicsComponentBottom.physicsBody (there is physicsBottom node, but i guess that is another node)

Comment: change my code to simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the way to set the `physicsBody` in my project and couldn't reproduce your problem.
However,by compared the code between yours and mine, I think your problem is that you create ONE `physicsBody` and set it to EVERY "collider" you create, which is related to the copying issues.
Perhaps this can be fixed by adding `copy` method:

```
renderComponent.node.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[[physicsComponentBottom.physicsBody copy]
                                                                   ]];
```

---

I read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skphysicsbody) later and find the restriction of the method,that it only support `volume-based` physicsBody.This might be your problem.

> Sprite Kit supports two kinds of physics bodies, volume-based bodies and edge-based bodies. When you create a physics body, its kind, size, and shape are determined by the constructor method you call. An edge-based body does not have mass or volume and is unaffected by forces or impulses in the system. Edge-based bodies are used to represent volume-less boundaries or hollow spaces in your physics simulation. In contrast, volume-based bodies are used to represent objects with mass and volume.

Comment: Working!! Thanks for your kind. I read again and I found that. I miss     self.physicsBody.density = 1;. I'll study how to set value. Thank you again kind guy.